# "You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause". How to delete rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

```
 delete t1 from pg_acymailing_listsub t1
        join pg_acymailing_subscriber tt on t1.subid = tt.subid
        join pg_users t2 on tt.userid = t2.id
    where NOW() > t2.registerDate + interval 90 day and t1.listid=7 and (
        exists (
            SELECT * FROM pg_acymailing_listsub WHERE pg_acymailing_listsub.listid=1 AND pg_acymailing_listsub.subid = t1.subid AND pg_acymailing_listsub.status=-1 LIMIT 1
        ) OR t1.subid not in (
            select pg_acymailing_userstats.subid from pg_acymailing_userstats where pg_acymailing_userstats.subid = t1.subid and pg_acymailing_userstats.open > 0
        )
    );
```

What the problem? I think there need to use subqueries, but I not imagine how to use it in my query.

Comment: there is no `update`???

Comment: wrong delete syntax: replace `delete t1 from` with `delete from`

Comment: Changed with `delete from`, but error: `1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't1 join pg_acymailing_subscriber tt on t1.subid = tt.subid join ' at line 1`

Answer (score 0):

I admit that the error message is hard to follow.  It should really say `delete`.  But the problem is the reference to `pg_acymailing_listsub` in the `EXISTS` subquery, and that is among the tables you want to delete from.

MySQL does not allow references in subqueries to the table being deleted from . . . unless you use a materialization hack.

However, this should be easy to fix by adding another `JOIN` clause to the `FROM`.  You seem to know how to do that.

Comment: I don't know where specificaly to add `JOIN` clause you suggest

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
delete t1 from pg_acymailing_listsub t1
        join pg_acymailing_subscriber tt on t1.subid = tt.subid
        join pg_users t2 on tt.userid = t2.id
        join pg_acymailing_listsub t3 on t3subid=t1.subid and t3.listid=1 and t3.[status]=-1
        join pg_acymailing_userstats t4 on t4.subid = t1.subid AND t4.[open]<=0
 where NOW() > t2.registerDate + interval 90 day and t1.listid=7
```

Comment: Tried replace `delete t1` with `select count(*)`, it returns me 55695 rows instead of 7783. And it's about I have maximum 30000 rows, and it can't return 55695